# Having trouble understanding the recursive portion of a binary tree DFS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, nodes

I've written this function via trial and error, and I can't seem to understand how the recursive portion is adding the first element or in this case the `1->` in both the paths.  Here is the code:

```
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
}

const binaryTreePaths = root => {
    if (!root) return null
    let results = []
    const dfs = (node, path) => {
        if (!node.left && !node.right) return results.push(path + node.val)
        if (node.left) dfs(node.left, path + node.val + '->')
        if (node.right) dfs(node.right, path + node.val + '->')
    }
    dfs(root, '')
    return results
}

const tree1 = new TreeNode(1)
tree1.left = new TreeNode(2)
tree1.right = new TreeNode(3)
tree1.left.right = new TreeNode(5)

console.log(binaryTreePaths(tree1))
```

The recursive calls to the left and right nodes add left and right children to the path which I understand, but what in the function adds the first node?

Comment: The recursive calls *do* add the `node.val` to the `path` that is used as the argument for the recursive call. They don't add the left value and the right value, but they add the *current* value (that `1`) before doing the recursion to the left and right nodes.

Comment: Can you point out the specific line which adds the `1`?; unfortunately, I am still failing to see where it happens.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to refactor the function a bit:

```
const dfs = (node, parentPath) => {
    const path = parentPath + node.val;
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^ magic happens here
    if (!node.left && !node.right) return results.push(path)
    if (node.left) dfs(node.left, path + '->')
    if (node.right) dfs(node.right, path + '->')
}
```

Try stepping through this with a debugger, and log the value of `parentPath` and `path`.